How to draw a spiral with bezierCurveTo in html canvas?
I want to draw a spiral, a circle where the radius steadily increases with the angle.
When searching for similar questions, the circle/spiral is always approximated by drawing a lot of lines with the lineTo method. The more lines are used, the more the circle/spiral is approximated. But using a lot of lines has a performance disadvantage, so the programmer needs to weight up "performance" vs "appearance".
The bezierCurveTo on the other hand could draw a perfect spiral, without a huge performance disadvantage, but I don't know how to calculate the control points for the bezier method.
Playground for drawing the spiral with the lineTo method: JSFiddle Playground
context.save();
context.beginPath();
let offset = initialRadius;
for (let turn = 0; turn < turnCount; turn++) {
    for (let step = 0; step < stepCount; step++) {
        context.lineTo(offset, 0);
        offset += growthPerTurn / stepCount;
        context.rotate(360 / stepCount * Math.PI / 180);
    }
}
context.lineWidth = 3;
context.strokeStyle = "yellow";
context.stroke();
context.restore();

Here is my first attempt to approximate the spiral with bezier: JSFiddle Playground
(determined the value for temp through trial and error)
context.moveTo(initialRadius, 0);
const temp = 1.25;
for (let turn = 0; turn < turnCount; turn++) {
    for (let step = 1; step <= stepsPerTurn; step++) {
        const points = [
            [temp * calculateOffset(turn, step -0.66) * Math.cos(calculateAngle(step - 0.66)), temp * calculateOffset(turn, step -0.66) * Math.sin(calculateAngle(step - 0.66))],
            [temp * calculateOffset(turn, step -0.33) * Math.cos(calculateAngle(step - 0.33)), temp * calculateOffset(turn, step -0.33) * Math.sin(calculateAngle(step - 0.33))],
            [calculateOffset(turn, step) * Math.cos(calculateAngle(step)),calculateOffset(turn, step) * Math.sin(calculateAngle(step))],
        ];
        context.bezierCurveTo(points[0][0], points[0][1], points[1][0], points[1][1], points[2][0], points[2][1]);
    }
}


what makes you think that a Bezier method "could draw a perfect spiral"? Also, there are different kinds of "spiral" curves.

The radius of the spiral should increase proportionally to the angle. Or what do you mean with kinds of "spiral" curves?

There are spirals where the "arms" stay the same distance apart, other spirals where the distance grows, and among those there are rates of "expansion" that follow different patterns. You might want to look into the mathematics of the concept of "spiral" sets.

I'm pretty sure you can't get a mathematically perfect spiral with cubic Bezier curves. I think Raph Levien has some insights on this... https://raphlinus.github.io/curves/2018/12/08/euler-spiral.html

For best fit use line segments
Using a bezier will likely be more of an approximation than using line segments..
If you set the length of each line segment to be only a few pixels long you will get a very accurate spiral that at most will be only a fraction of a pixel out.
In the snippet the change in angle is half the line segment length divided by the radius times PI.
The radius is the current angle times a slope value radiusChange
To prevent infinite loop ensure the lineSegLength is not zero
To prevent a divide by zero check that the changing radius does not = zero
Full page the snippet for more detail.


const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
function drawSpiral(x, y, radiusChange, maxRadius, lineSegLength = 1) {
  if (Math.abs(lineSegLength) > 0.5) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    lineSegLength *= 0.5;
    var a = 0, r = radiusChange * lineSegLength;
    while (r < maxRadius && Math.abs(r) > 1e-5) {
      a += lineSegLength / r * Math.PI;   // next point at approx lineSegLength pixel distance 
      r = a * radiusChange;
      ctx.lineTo(x + Math.cos(a) * r, y + Math.sin(a) * r);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
drawSpiral(200, 200, 4, 180);
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>



Forcing Beziers
Beziers will never fit a spiral, the best you can do is an approximation.
The code below uses beziers (quadratic and cubic).
Using quadratic beziers (red) and cubic (green) drawn over the best fit line method used in the snippet above.
The spiral is animated to show that the bezier fit is independent of the spiral slope radiusChange


function drawSpiral(x, y, radiusChange, maxRadius, lineSegLength = 1) {
  if (Math.abs(lineSegLength) > 0.5) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    lineSegLength *= 0.5;
    var a = 0, r = radiusChange * lineSegLength;
    while (r < maxRadius && Math.abs(r) > 1e-5) {
      a += lineSegLength / r * Math.PI;   // next point at approx lineSegLength pixel distance 
      r = a * radiusChange;
      ctx.lineTo(x + Math.cos(a) * r, y + Math.sin(a) * r);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function drawBezSpiral(x, y, radiusChange, maxRadius) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    const angStep = Math.PI * 0.5;
    const angHalfStep = Math.PI * 0.25;
    var rad = 0, ang = angStep, angH = ang - angHalfStep;
    while (rad < maxRadius) {
      const radH = angH * radiusChange * 1.31;
      rad = ang * radiusChange;
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
          x + Math.cos(angH) * radH, y + Math.sin(angH) * radH,
          x + Math.cos(ang) * rad, y + Math.sin(ang) * rad
      )
      ang += angStep;
      angH += angStep;
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
function drawCubicBezSpiral(x, y, radiusChange, maxRadius) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    const angStep = Math.PI * 0.5;
    const angOffset = angStep * (1 / 3);
    var rad = 0, ang = angStep, ang2 = ang - angOffset, ang1 = ang2 - angOffset;
    while (rad < maxRadius) {
      const rad1 = ang1 * radiusChange * 1.15;
      const rad2 = ang2 * radiusChange * 1.15;
      rad = ang * radiusChange;
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(
          x + Math.cos(ang1) * rad1, y + Math.sin(ang1) * rad1,
          x + Math.cos(ang2) * rad2, y + Math.sin(ang2) * rad2,
          x + Math.cos(ang) * rad,   y + Math.sin(ang) * rad
      )
      ang += angStep;
      ang1 += angStep;
      ang2 += angStep;
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
var W = canvas.width;
var H = canvas.height;
function mainLoop(time) {
    if (W !== innerWidth || H !== innerHeight) {
        canvas.width = W = innerWidth;
        canvas.height = H = innerHeight;
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,W,H);

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#0004"
    const slope = Math.sin(time * 0.0005) * 10 + 14;
    drawSpiral(W * 0.5 | 0, H * 0.5 | 0, slope, W * 0.5 | 0);

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#F00"
    drawBezSpiral(W * 0.5 | 0, H * 0.5 | 0, slope, W * 0.5 | 0);

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#0A0"
    drawCubicBezSpiral(W * 0.5 | 0, H * 0.5 | 0, slope, W * 0.5 | 0);
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);;
}
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>




As described, I want to avoid drawing many segments. For comparison: I added a playground to the question where I achieve a rather good-looking spiral with just 3 bezier-segments.

@GniLudio I think you are over complicating a simple operation,  Beziers are slower to render than line segments (I don't know where the balance of performance is between the two) and the added complexity of aligning and scaling bezier tangents will nullify any performance gain you get. BTW the JSFiddle spiral has very obvious joins. (control points on successive beziers are not aligned and scaled)

Since I want to remove certain parts of the canvas, I need to redraw the canvas almost every frame. I tried doing that with the lineTo method, but that leads to a laggy performance. That the bezier curve (with less segments) is more performant is just an assumption (for now).
And yes, I know that the JSFiddle spiral has visible joints, but that should (I think) be fixable through selecting a better value for temp. (e.g. 1.3: https://jsfiddle.net/q3xzrnev/)

How about a more mathematical approach...
We can think of a spiral as a circle with a variable diameter that keeps getting smaller
A circle
We can draw a circle with many dots and a bit of trigonometry


var ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");

var diam = 80
var frame = 0

function drawDot(x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function loop() {
  let angle = (frame++ % 360)
  let a = angle * Math.PI / 180
  drawDot(100 + diam * Math.cos(a), 100 + diam * Math.sin(a))
  if (angle == 360) clearInterval(inter)
}

inter = setInterval(loop, 10);
<canvas id="c" width=200 height=200></canvas>



A spiral
Now that we know how to draw a circle we can make reduce the diameter on every frame


var ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");

var diam = 80
var frame = 0

function drawDot(x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function loop() {
  let angle = (frame++ % 360)
  let a = angle * Math.PI / 180
  drawDot(100 + diam * Math.cos(a), 100 + diam * Math.sin(a))
  diam -= 0.05
  if (diam < 20) clearInterval(inter)
}

inter = setInterval(loop, 10);
<canvas id="c" width=200 height=200></canvas>




... and another example


var ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");

var diam = 95
var frame = 0
var delta = 0

function drawDot(x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function loop() {
  let angle = (frame++ % 360)
  let a = angle * Math.PI / 180
  drawDot(100 + diam * Math.cos(a), 100 + diam * Math.sin(a))
  diam -= delta
  if (angle % 45 == 0) delta += 0.01
  if (diam < 5) clearInterval(inter)
}

inter = setInterval(loop, 10);
<canvas id="c" width=200 height=200></canvas>



A spiral with Path2d
The previous examples all create an animated spiral drawing many elements, but we could use the same logic to build a Path2D that we just draw once


class Spiral {
  constructor(x, y, line_width, max_diam, min_diam, init_angle) {
    this.path = new Path2D()
    let frame = init_angle
    let delta = 0
    while (max_diam > min_diam) {
      let angle = (frame++ % 360)
      let a = angle * Math.PI / 180
      this.path.arc(
        x + max_diam * Math.cos(a),
        y + max_diam * Math.sin(a),
        line_width, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
      max_diam -= delta
      if (angle % 45 == 0) delta += 0.01
    }
  }

  draw(ctx, color) {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.strokeStyle = color
    ctx.stroke(this.path)
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");
big = new Spiral(100, 100, 1, 95, 10, 90)
smalls = [
  new Spiral(240, 40, 3, 40, 1, 0),
  new Spiral(280, 120, 3, 40, 1, 45),
  new Spiral(340, 60, 3, 40, 1, 180)
]

big.draw(ctx, "red")
smalls.forEach((x) => x.draw(ctx, "blue"));
<canvas id="c" width=400 height=200></canvas>




As described, I want to avoid drawing many line segments. I added a playground where a lot less bezier segments are used to achieve a spiral to the question.

@GniLudio If you want to avoid drawing many elements you could use a Path2D to build one Spiral then you draw it just once... I added an example at the bottom of my answer

Thanks. I will try to use that. But is it possible to remove parts of a path?
I want to draw and fade out the spiral over time. (The start of the spiral should fade out first)

@GniLudio NO I do not see any way to have an "animated fade out" like you suggest, while also avoid drawing many elements ... if you draw many elements you have control of each individual one, that way you can apply alpha and give the illusion of a fading away

You mentioned in the comments "fade out the spiral over time" so that is some sort of animation ...
Theres is a character for spiral ꩜ maybe you can use that, I've done some animations that you can use as inspiration for your own fade out effect, see sample code below


var ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d")
var i = 1499
var delta = -3

function loop() {
  ctx.reset()
  ctx.font = "150px Arial";
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.setLineDash([i, 1500]);
  ctx.strokeText("꩜ ꩜", 10, 110);
  i += delta
  if (i > 1500 || i < 50)
    delta *= -1
}

setInterval(loop, 10)
<canvas id="c" width=400 height=140></canvas>




Another sample only printing a portion of the charecter


var ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d")
var i = delta = 3

function loop() {
  ctx.reset()
  ctx.font = "150px Arial";
  ctx.lineWidth = 6;
  ctx.setLineDash([0, 240, i, 1300]);
  ctx.strokeText("꩜", 10, 110);
  i += delta
  if (i > 430 || i < 2)
    delta *= -1
}

setInterval(loop, 40)
<canvas id="c" width=200 height=140></canvas>



